Why does my NuGet pack task in my Azure Pipeline not use my Azure Artifacts feed?
My Azure Pipeline is failing when it uses the NuGet pack command. Here is the error:-
error NU1101: Unable to find package Repositories.Abstractions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

Here is the pack task that is failing:-
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Create NuGet Package
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: '**/${{ parameters.nuGetPackageToBuild }}.csproj'
      versioningScheme: 'byBuildNumber'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: 'd4d1f2ae-4068-405e-93b1-etc. etc. etc. etc.'


It fails because it isn't using my Azure Artifacts feed. Here is the output from the command confirming that is doesn't try to use my feed:-
Feeds used:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs

As you can see I have added the "feedsToUse" and "vstsFeed" parameters to the pack command (above) in the vain hope that it might use them but I already know that the vstsFeed parameter is only used when the NuGet command is restore.
What confuses me is that in the same Azure Pipeline I have this command which succeeds just fine (although it is in a different job):-
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      name: 'NuGetRestore'
      displayName: 'NuGet Restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/Osprey.NuGet.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: 'd4d1f2ae-4068-405e-93b1-etc. etc. etc. etc.'


I can't work out how to get the pack command to use the Azure Artifacts feed. Any ideas?

I tried using below pipeline and it worked for Azure artifact feed:-
Make sure you specify your nuget feed url in the nuget.config file inside your directory:-
nuget.config:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureArtifacts" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxxx38/_packaging/xxxxxxx738/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- Add other package sources if needed -->
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Azure Devops yaml code:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

parameters:
- name: nuGetPackageToBuild
  type: string
  default: 'net6appdevops' 

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Create NuGet Package
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/${{ parameters.nuGetPackageToBuild }}.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'  
    versionEnvVar: 'BUILD_BUILDNUMBER'  
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/nuget.config'

Output:-


Thanks, Siddesh. That was the answer. FWIW I also needed to add this task to each job:-

task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

Everything is working correctly now.
(Unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as correct until I have 15 reputation but, for the record, it is correct).
